# The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ourchatapp/constants.dart';

class RoundedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Function press;
  final Color color, textColor;
  const RoundedButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.press,
    this.color = kPrimaryColor,
    this.textColor = Colors.white,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      width: size.width * 0.8,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(29),
        child: newElevatedButton(),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget newElevatedButton() {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(color: textColor),
      ),
      onPressed: press,
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: color,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40, vertical: 20),
          textStyle: TextStyle(
              color: textColor, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
    );
  }
}
```

**I want to design my own button, when I add it to the relevant pages, I get such an error and when I click the button, it does not switch between the pages.
I have created login and sign up buttons on the welcome screen, but when I click on these buttons, they do not switch to the relevant pages. please help me**

Comment: Try your onPressed function like - `onPressed:()=> press,`

Comment: thank you, error gone but not switching page RoundedButton(
              text: "SIGN UP",
              color: kPrimaryLightColor,
              textColor: Colors.black,
              press: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return SignUpScreen();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),

Comment: your code is working correct just try to hot restart your project or Stop and restart your project or used `final VoidCallback press` instead of  `final Function press;`

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work lol

Comment: it works when i use normal button but not on my own button lol

Comment: oh i finally figured it out thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `press` type from `Function` to `VoidCallback`, so your press parameter should look like this:

```
final VoidCallback press
```

Or try this:

```
onPressed : press.call()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the press as Function type so you change -

```
onPressed: press,
```

to -

```
onPressed: () => press(),
```

these way you will call the function and it will change the page.